# Why is the CORS Response Cookie not stored in Browser?

Tags: javascript, cookies, authorization, credentials, httponly

The Frontend JavaScript sends a CORS fetch POST with login credentials to the backend. However the Set-Cookie (for authentication) in the response from the backend is not stored in the browser, why is that the case?

The Set-Cookie is shown in the fetch response and gets recognized as a http Cookie from the browser, however it doesn't get saved.

I've been through a lot of entries on this issue and checked things like "credentials: 'include'", the correct Response Headers and SameSite properties of the cookie.

Would really appreciate someone's expert opinion, since I couldn't resolve the issue for days now. ;)

---

This is the webpage for login:
https://www.evs-media.com/tests/t5

For the backend I'm using a Rest API No-Code Tool: https://www.xano.com

Domain Frontend: https://www.evs-media.com
Domain Backend API: https://x8ki-letl-twmt.n7.xano.io/api:s900chrT

On the backend server-side this is what the Request Header looks like:

```
"Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors"
"Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty"
"Dnt: 1","Origin: https://www.evs-media.com"
"Content-Type: multipart/form-databoundary=---------------------------32748419764181237672921298736"
"Referer: https://www.evs-media.com/"
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5"
"Accept: */*","User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"
"Content-Length: 295"
"X-Scheme: https"
"X-Forwarded-Scheme: https"
"X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
"X-Forwarded-Port: 443"
"X-Forwarded-Host: x8ki-letl-twmt.n7.xano.io"
"X-Forwarded-For: 79.242.71.235"
"X-Real-Ip: 79.242.71.235"
"X-Request-Id: c459f42dad416f9b5d0d53df307632e9"
"Host: x8ki-letl-twmt.n7.xano.io"
```

This is the Response Header on the backend server-side:

```
"Accept-Ranges: none"
"X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block"
"X-Frame-Options: deny"
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS, HEAD"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, X-APP-KEY, X-Data-Source, X-Branch"
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"
"Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400"
"X-App: hit"
"set-cookie: myfirstcookie= Bearer eyJhbGciOiJBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwiemlwIjoiREVGIn0.jowMcpyEUJZPSxDuIWbGRT2IMabWHfYkBX9tr0_t0agn8wkAKFlc5tUPGpAdKf-9Rhgo8IE5oCwKTNJ0hL1VqZv2D4Vl2XJC.614vZOklc-w9tlAcpxf8Sw.d1OGC6ownAZid1q0XwbGOVP_AKTCMuPG9ehcCbG2iklLHzAeela9r_78t5IN30FwcgHkxNPlh0opQuw5t1DXqjosVTWwgdFzOhv_Add4vznjo_Gd6bv-tnFOLeQVlcfLb3CNzGvHcC8rII9rEy_HjcNx9Xv9DqXIM7i2KPYf33Q.mLjsCPzAUINdZLPydsJyaHNI8v6AISAU8mvz0pRrLw4; Expires=Wed 20 Jul 2022 07:28:00 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; Domain=.x8ki-letl-twmt.n7.xano.io/api:s900chrT; path=/; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly;"
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.evs-media.com"
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie"
"Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

This is what the Request Headers look like on the frontend client-side:
[Screeenshot of Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy5DE.png)

This is the fetch JavaScript on the frontend:

```
const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

const formData = new FormData(this);

fetch('https://x8ki-letl-twmt.n7.xano.io/api:s900chrT/auth/logintest', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include' ,
    body: formData
}).then(function (response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
})
})
```